# Add gmail as smarthost in Debian exim4

Tags: gmail, debian, exim4, smarthost

I'd like to know how to setup my exim4 on Debian so that it can use gmail as the smarthost, rather than my ISP. It appears to need TLS to be setup, and of course a gmail userid and password. The "standard" smarthost example that comes with exim4 in Debian doesn't have these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above solution didn't work for some reason but the solution here worked for me.

http://www.manu-j.com/blog/wordpress-exim4-ubuntu-gmail-smtp/75/

The only change I did was to use `xyz@mydomain.com` instead of `xyz@gmail.com` in the “begin authenticators” section.

Answer (score 1):

First, install stunnel4 and configure it to map `[127.0.0.1]:587` to `smtp.gmail.com:465` like this:

```
client=yes
[smtp-gmail]
accept = 587
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Then reconfigure exim4:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Configure exim4 to use a lot of small files, smarthost through localhost:587

Edit /etc/exim4/passwd.client and add:

```
localhost:yourname@gmail.com:yourpassword
```

Remember to check permissions, and then run:

```
update-exim4.conf
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it. Why must stunnel be used, i.e. why can't exim4 coomunicate with gmail's smtp host directly?

Comment: I don't think it "must" - merely that this is easier to explain.

Comment: I've voted this down as I never liked having to use another piece of software (stunnel) where it should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

See the instructions on Debian Wiki:

http://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4